# Identify this relation to be an injection, surjection, bijection or non-function

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

Identify this relation as an injection, surjection, bijection or non-function, where $f:A \rightarrow B$, with $x$ an element of $A$, and the value of $f$ is determined by:

$f(x)=$ the number of elements of $x$, $A=\{\text{subsets of U}\}$, $B=\{\text{non-negative numbers}\}$

So I know for a surjection there needs to be more items in the domain than the range. In this case there would be more numbers in the domain since the universal set contains all numbers and set $B$ is just non-negative numbers. Is this thinking correct? Would this be a surjection?

Comment: Does $U$ mean the universal set here, or is it just some arbitrary set called $U$?  If $U$ is the universal set, then what is $f(x)$ if $x\subset U$ contains infinitely many elements?

Comment: We can indeed say that if $f:A \to B$ is a surjective function, then there are at least as many elements in $A$ as in $B$.  However, the converse does not hold.

Comment: honestly my teacher didn't specify. On the review sheet they put a fancy U so I'm assuming they meant the universal set.

Comment: was my reasoning for why I believed it to be a surjection accurate or no?

Comment: As stated it is incorrect, or at the very least incomplete.

Comment: ok, based on the information provided would you conclude it is a surjection? Sorry I am just really confused how to answer this question

Comment: Yes, I would conclude that it is surjection (assuming the domain and range are changed so that the function makes sense for infinite sets).  user137630's answer below gives a valid way to conclude that $f$ is a surjection but not an injection.

Comment: since you're have trouble with surjectivity, consider the following: let $A = \{1,2,3\}$ and let $B = \{1,2\}$.  Define $f:A \to B$ by $f(x) = 1$ for all $x \in A$.  $A$ has more elements than $B$.  Why isn't $f$ surjective?  Take $A = \Bbb R$ and $B = \{1,2\}$.  Again, define $f(x) = 1$ for all $x \in A$.  $A$ has many more elements than $B$.  Why isn't $f$ surjective?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that this is a surjection since for any nonnegative number there exists a set with that cardinality. Of course it is not an injection. It is a function (every set has a uniquely determined cardinality), it is defined on the whole $A$ only if you include in $B$ also the value $\infty$, otherwise sets with infinitely many elements would not have an image.

Comment: what do you mean by cardinality? Sorry can you simplify this explanation?

Comment: The cardinality of a set is, intuitively the number of its elements (it is exactly the number of its elements if this number is finite). When the set contains infinitely many points, some cautions are in order: one can say that the cardinality is $\infty$, but there are different kinds of infinity: the natural numbers are far less than the real numbers, for instance.

Comment: ok so this function is a surjection because there are far fewer natural numbers than real numbers and for a surjection there needs be more items in the domain than the range?

Comment: Surjective means that every element in the target space lies in the image, i.e. for every element $b$ in the image $B$ there is an element $a$ in $A$ such that $f(a)=b$. This is false if there are more elements in $B$ than in $A$. However, $A$ being bigger than $B$ is a necessary, not sufficient condition for the map to be a surjection: you may have $A$ bigger than $B$ but a map that sends every element in $A$ to the same $b$ in $B$. In this case, all other elements in $B$ are not hit by $f$, which is then not surjective.

Comment: ok, So I understand the domain being larger than the range isn't always necessary because the two sets could have an equal number in each and be a surjection. What do you mean by all other elements in b are not "hit by" f?

Comment: no, the point is, $A$ having a bigger than (or equal to, as you point out) number of elements of $B$ IS necessary, but not sufficient. By not hit by $f$ I mean that all the other elements in $B$ are not in the image of the function, though they lie in the target space. This (target $\neq$ image) is what makes the function not surjective.